# ES6 class: set return of function as a prototype method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Lets say I need an event listener for a window scroll event and I want to store this listener as a method on the prototype of an ES6 class. It's easy. But I also need a debounce function to reduce the number of executions of the handler (Ex. _.debounce() from lodash). So, I need a reference to the method returned by _.debounce() to be used as the listener, so I can bind and unbind it when needed. What is the best approach to do this with ES6 classes? **The point is: can we set the result of an expression as a prototype method with ES6 syntax?**

```
class MyClass {

   constructor () {
      this.prop1 = 0;
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.myListener.bind(this));
   }

   // Is it possible?
   myListener = _.debounce(() => {
      this.prop1 = 1;
   }, 200);   

}
```

Comment: If you debounce `myListener` in the class definition, the debounce count will be shared across all instances (so only one instance would see the event). You have to add the debounce in the constructor to tie to the instance.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to store the bound and debounced function as a property of your instance:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor () {
        this.prop1 = 0;
        this.boundListener = _.debounce(this.myListener.bind(this), 200);
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.boundListener);
    }
    myListener() {
        this.prop1 = 1;
    }
    something() { // called later
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.boundListener);
    }
}
```

You will have to bind and debounce the method per instance, otherwise it won't know which object `this.prop1` refers to and the debouncing would interfere with other instances. You cannot do this on the prototype. You could however leave out the prototype completely:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor () {
        this.prop1 = 0;
        this.myListener = _.debounce(() => {
            this.prop1 = 1;
        }, 200);   
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.myListener);
    }
    something() { // called later
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.myListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Bergi. I did exactly this. But, I was wondering if we could set the result of an expression as a prototype method with ES6 syntax...

Comment: @MatheusDal'Pizzol: Yes: `MyClass.prototype.myListener = <anExpression>;`.

Comment: Hey, Felix! Thank you too! But this is standard ES5 syntax. As I said: I wonder if it's possible to achieve this with ES6 syntax...

Comment: @MatheusDal'Pizzol All ES5 syntax is ES6 syntax as well… No, it's not possible to do this inside a `class`. And as I explained, you don't want this anyway.

Comment: Yeah, @Bergi. I'm aware of this. I was just wondering about the possibility. Now I know it can't be done, so I wont waste my time if someday I end up thinking of doing this. Thanks for all the answers!